Can I initialize a PDA (again) after I deleted it (Anchor)?
I calculated the PDA of an account using the public key of my local wallet, then I initialized it on-chain (using the canonical bump). One of my tests tries deleting the account, which works, but then I need to initialize this same PDA again to try other functionalities.
I'm getting an error when trying to initialize the same PDA again:
Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x0

So I have some questions:

Considering that I deleted the account using #[account(close = signer)], can I use the same PDA again or is this PDA forbidden from being used?
Would I need to recalculate the PDA to use a new bump, or can I use the same PDA?



Yes, you can reuse the same PDA after deleting the associated account using #[account(close = signer)].
It's generally considered a best practice to recalculate the bump seed using getProgramDerivedAddress before each initialisation attempt.

